# Enable kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone in Alpine Linux

Tags: docker, amazon-web-services, alpine-linux

I'm trying to setup puppeteer to work in my docker container which is based on the node:alpine image. I'm not able to run the image as a privileged user because I'm using AWS Fargate (which doesn't allow this option).

So I need to enable user namespace cloning as described here: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#setting-up-chrome-linux-sandbox

I've tried adding this line to my Dockerfile:

```
RUN sysctl -w kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1
```

I get this error when building the docker image:

```
sysctl: error: 'kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone' is an unknown key
```

Is there a special way to enable namespace cloning in Alpine Linux which is different to normal distributions of Linux?

Answer (score 0):

<s>Add `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN` to your `docker run ...` command</s>

**EDIT**: As noted in the comments, AWS Fargate does not currently support `--cap-add`.

AFAIK, Alpine's kernel doesn't support `unprivileged_userns_clone`. You can run the [script](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Garbee/dfd33ba0a62f1cbc023b8d57de18efca/raw/f82ed513014062554a3536980a67390b57f1f858/user-namespace-check-linux.sh) in this [reply](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/290#issuecomment-322885826) on an [issue opened against puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/290) to test.

I never figured out why the [Setup setuid sandbox](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#alternative-setup-setuid-sandbox) instructions didn't work on Alpine. In my instance, I had installed chromium from the Alpine repo instead of using the bundled version that comes with puppeteer.

The solution came from [this issue on puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3740#issuecomment-690121056).

Comment: Careful, using `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN` is roughly equivalent to running the container as root, which is contrary to what the OP is trying to setup.

Comment: Ah - you are correct. Fargate does not support `--cap-add` only `--cap-drop`. While the answer isn't a solution, it does contain info about Alpine's support for namespace cloning. I'll edit to remove the `--cap-add` bit to minimize confusion.